# View/edit Mac OS X's Finder labels from a Windows PC

Tags: windows, macos, dropbox, finder, label

Is it possible to view and/or edit the Mac's Finder labels (applied to folders and/or files) from a Windows PC?

We are sharing files via Dropbox and it'd be nice if the few Windows users we have could see the labels.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/245925/color-tag-files-in-windows-7-like-on-mac) is close but I don't think the colors are shared between OS X & Windows.

Comment: It's possible, although you would have to script something that could interface with properties that are set in OS X.

Comment: In theory, it's possible. The label info is stored in the .ds_store and other annoying Mac-generated files that reside in folders. If you can find a program to read those, then it's pretty likely.