# Mac Finder Color-Tags synced with windows on NAS

Tags: windows, windows-10, mac, nas, finder

I found this entry: [Is it possible to Color-tag files in Windows 7, like in Finder on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/245925/is-it-possible-to-color-tag-files-in-windows-7-like-in-finder-on-a-mac)

But unfortunately it has no solution and also I would like to go a little bit further.

Is there a way, to display/ sync the color tags from mac Finder to windows if the files are on a NAS? 
For sure I would need 3rd party software. But I couldn't find any.

If there is no other way I would also install 3rd party software on mac that syncs tags on files between both os

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing on Windows that can read Mac Finder tags - I've been looking for years (though I'd be happy to be proven wrong;)

Interestingly, If you transfer files to a Windows machine with Finder tags already attached, you can still see them from a Mac. You can also add or remove them from a Mac whilst they're on the Windows share *[whether or not they're even Mac-readable files]*. e.g.
[image]

but Windows still can't see them
[image]

<sup>Fairly random old file chosen for example.</sup>

I've never tried this on a NAS, only on shared Windows locations.